# Create a HAPI route prerequisite to get some value from REST API

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

How to create a route prerequisite to get some value from REST API? How to implement **getCount** function to wait until API response and use it in the route handler function? (Please note that I'm using Hapi 8.3.1)

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/products',
    config: {
        state: {
            failAction: 'ignore'
        },
        pre:[{method:getCount, assign: 'count'}],
        handler: function (request, reply) {

            console.log(request.pre.count);

            reply({products}).code(200);
        }
    }
});

function getCount(request, reply){
    http.get('/products/count/')
    // how to implement this to wait till get product count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to wait for the HTTP request to complete before the code continues? In that case, you will need to make getCount an async function, and await the get request. You should also use fetch() instead of http.get(). So, you would end up with this:

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/products',
    config: {
        state: {
            failAction: 'ignore'
        },
        pre:[{method:getCount, assign: 'count'}],
        handler: function (request, reply) {

            console.log(request.pre.count);

            reply({products}).code(200);
        }
    }
});

async function getCount(request, reply){
    let count = await fetch('/products/count/');
    return count;
}
```

This will wait for the request to complete before returning the value. It is also possible to use .then() and Promises to do this if your node version does not support async/await. Using that would yield code like this:

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/products',
    config: {
        state: {
            failAction: 'ignore'
        },
        pre:[{method:getCount, assign: 'count'}],
        handler: function (request, reply) {

            console.log(request.pre.count);

            reply({products}).code(200);
        }
    }
});

function getCount(request, reply){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      fetch('/products/count/').then(function(result) {
        resolve(result); 
      }).catch(function (err) {
        reject(err);
      });
    });
}
```